# Java generic: why type erasure won't allow check instance of generic

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I read [Java Criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Java) about why Type erasure makes java less powerful then some languages in generic. In wiki page, here is one example:

```
public class MyClass<E> {
    public static void myMethod(Object item) {
        if (item instanceof E) {  //Compiler error
            ...
        }
        E item2 = new E();   //Compiler error
        E[] iArray = new E[10]; //Compiler error
    }
}
```

I understand why `E item2 = new E();` should be compiled error because we really don't know class E before calling them. But I don't know why this line should be error:

```
if (item instanceof E) {  //Compiler error
   ...
}
```

Because as I know, when compiling java application, all generic type will replaced by its concreted type. for example:

```
// all E will be substituted by Integer 
MyClass<Integer> myObject = new MyClass<Integer>();
```

So I don't think why should Java throws compile error at above line.

Comment: Type erasure means the exact opposite of that. `E` gets substituted by `Object`.

Comment: Even without type erasure, there's no guarantee that that constructor even exists for T. OO in java doesn't have a mechanism for defining what constructors look like.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I suspect that's what OP means by "`new E();` should be compiled error because we really don't know class E". (By his own logic, `new E()` is as (in)valid as `new Integer()`.)

Comment: I don't really understand this point. I accept that List<E> will become List<Object>. but object insides still keep their type. so why `instance_of E` should not work.

Comment: for example we don't use generic but we use raw list then we insert many objects (of any types). After that, we can get each object and use instance_of operator. why this shouldn't work for generic.

Comment: If `E` becomes `Object`, `instanceof E` would become `instanceof Object`, which is obviously pointless.

Comment: What should `item instanceof E` mean? As far as `MyClass` is concerned, `E` is any subclass of `Object`. Therefore `item instanceof E` can only mean `item instanceof Object`. But this test is completely useless - any `item` is always an `instanceof Object`!